# Can i use a while loop to shorten this Scala code

Tags: scala, loops, while-loop

this code could be very long and ugly, is there a way of me shortening it down using a while loop or anything else? im new to scala programming

```
object VendingMachine {

/** You need to write a program to calculate the coins that a vending  
 *  machine should dispense as change in an 8 element array (one array
 *  element for each denomination of coin)
 *
 * For example:
 *      giveTheChange(242) gives Array(1,0,0,2,0,0,1,0)
 *      
 * As 242p = (1*£2)+(0*£1)+(0*50p)+(2*20p)+(0*10p)+(0*5p)+(1*2p)+(0*1p) 
 */
def giveTheChange(money : Int) : Array[Int] = {
    // TODO: Complete this method.
    // Write your solution here


    var change:Array[Int] = new Array[Int](8)
    var changegiven = money
    count = 0

    if(changegiven >= 200){
    count = changegiven / 200
    change(0) = count
    changegiven = changegive%200
    }

    return change()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. No explanation of the actual code deliberately, you're after an answer to an assignment. But some general hints - if you find yourself repeating code that's the same apart from the data operated on, then, yes, a while loop might be a possibility but in a language like Scala with a rich selection of functional programming features and a extensive collections library, there are other alternatives.

You want to iterate over the various coin sizes. You can do this with an array, and a loop over that array. I have a rule of thumb that if I'm using an index solely to retrieve the current element of the array (that is, the value of the index isn't significant in any other way) then there's probably a more elegant way to do it.

In Scala, we have many ways of iterating over a collection. `foldLeft` is suggestive, since it allows us to iterate over an array collecting something as we go, and here we want to collect the coins to use.

Another perspective: once I've processed the largest coin, I have some smaller amount of money left, and a smaller set of coins. So I have a smaller problem. Eventually, I have no coins and no money, and nothing more to do.  This divide-and-conquer approach suggests a recursive solution.

```
def giveTheChange(money:Int): Array[Int] = {
val coins = List(200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1)

  coins.foldLeft((List[Int](), money))
                { case ((change, amount), coin) => 
                     ((amount / coin) :: change, amount % coin) }
  ._1
  .reverse
  .toArray
}
giveTheChange(242)
//> res0: Array[Int] = Array(1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0)
```

and an alternative approach

```
  def giveTheChange2(money:Int): Array[Int] = {
    def gtChelper(coins:List[Int], money:Int):List[Int] = coins match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case c::t =>  (money / c) :: gtChelper(t, money % c)
    }
   val coins = List(200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1)
   gtChelper(coins, money).toArray
   }
   giveTheChange2(242) 
   //> res1: Array[Int] = Array(1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0)
```